# Trouble in constructing a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I construct a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of rational numbers such that it converges to a point $a$ which is irrational?

Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_n = {1 \over n} \lfloor nx \rfloor$. Then $x_n$ is rational for all $n$ and $x_n \to x$ for any $x$.

There is nothing special about the sequence $n$, any rational sequence $q_n$ such that $q_n \to \infty$ will do, that is
$x_n = {1 \over q_n} \lfloor q_n x \rfloor$.

Comment: Do you say about floor function?

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay: I don't understand your question?

Comment: I want to say that is it floor function of $nx$?

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay: It is, but either floor or ceiling will produce the same end result.

Comment: Ok.I have understood.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$1,1.4,1.41,1.414,1.4142.\ldots$, converges to $\sqrt2$

In general, for any real number $a=n.a_1a_2a_3a_4\ldots$, where $n$ is an integer and $a_i$ is a decimal digit, then the sequence $$n, n.a_1, n.a_1a_2, n.a_1a_2a_3, \ldots$$

converges to $a$.

Comment: How can I generalise this result?

Comment: Very minor point, you need to account for sign :-).

Comment: @copper.hat Well I said $n$ is an integer

Comment: Then you need to define what $(-n).a_1 a_2 \cdots$ means for $n >0$ :-)

Comment: @copper.hat Uh... no I don't.  Integers can be negative, so the case you mentioned is already accounted for.  Consider the number $-3.14159265...$.  $-3$ is an integer.

Comment: Not exactly, the $-$ applies to the entire number, not the first digit.

Comment: @copper.hat It doesn't matter.  Since the $-$ only applies to the first digit, the fractional part $.14159265$ can be thought of as the series $-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{4}{100}-\frac{1}{1000}-\frac{5}{10000}-\ldots$ whenever $n$ is negative.  I was trying to keep this answer brief, and I assumed this notion was intuitive to the OP.